# Scala: implementing Map with concrete types

Tags: scala, types

I'm running into some kind of quirk in the Scala type system that has me a bit stumped.  I am trying to make a class that extends Map[String,String] and I can't quite figure out how to implement the + method in such a way that the compiler accepts it.

Here's the code I have now:

```
class ParamMap(val pairs:List[(String,String)] = Nil) extends Map[String,String] {

  lazy val keyLookup = Map() ++ pairs

  override def get(key: String): Option[String] = keyLookup.get(key)
  override def iterator: Iterator[(String, String)] = pairs.reverseIterator

  /**
   * Add a key/value pair to the map
   */
  override def + [B1 >: String](kv: (String, B1)) = new ParamMap(kv :: pairs)

  /**
   * Remove all values for the given key from the map
   */
  override def -(key: String): ParamMap  = new ParamMap(pairs.filterNot(_._1 == key))

  /**
   * Remove a specific pair from the map
   */
  def -(kv: (String, String)) : ParamMap = new ParamMap(pairs - kv)
}
```

Scala tells me this:

```
type mismatch;  found: (String, B1)  required: (String, String)
```

I believe this is because B1 is allowed to be a subtype of String but my constructor expects just a String (?).  My original attempt was:

```
override def +(kv: (String, String)) = new ParamMap(kv :: pairs)
```

But this complained because the type signature didn't match the trait:

```
class ParamMap needs to be abstract, since method + in trait Map of type [B1 >: String](kv: (String, B1))scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,B1] is not defined
method + overrides nothing
```

I'm new to Scala and I think I'm getting over my head here in terms of how the type system works.  Perhaps I'll try messing with casting but I have a feeling there might be a "better way" that, if I know it, will save me a lot of trouble in the future.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some background about Scala's type system.

- The syntax `B1 >: String` means that `B1` is a *supertype* of `String`. So `B1` is less specific, and can't be cast to a `String`. Conversely, `B1 <: String` would be a *subtype* relationship.
- The definition of the `Map` trait is `Map [A, +B]`, where `A` represents the type of the key and `B` the type of the value. The `+B` notation says that `Map` is *covariant* in the key type, which means that `T <: S` implies `Map[A, T] <: Map[A, S]`.
- The full type of the `Map.+` method is `+ [B1 >: B] (kv: (A, B1)): Map[A, B1]`. The covariance of `B` kind of forces the use of `B1 >: B`. Here's an example of how it works: given a map `m: Map[String, String]` adding a key-value pair with a less specific type `kv : (String, Any)` will result in a less specific map, `(m + kv): Map[String, Any]`.

The last point illustrates the problem with your `ParamMap` definition. According to the `Map` interface, one should be able to add a key of type `Any` to a map of type `ParamMap <: Map[String, String]` and get back a `Map[String, Any]`. But you're trying to define `ParamMap.+` to always return `ParamMap[String, String]`, which is incompatible with `Map.+`.

One way to fix the problem is to give `ParamMap` an explicit type parameter, something like (warning untested),

```
class ParamMap[B](val pairs:List[(String,String)] = Nil) extends Map[String, B] {
  ...
  override def + [B1 >: B](kv: (String, B1)) = new ParamMap[B1](kv :: pairs)
}
```

but this may not be what you want. I don't think there's a way to fix the value type as `String` and implement the `Map[String, String]` interface.

---

Given all the above, why does the code in your answer compile?  You've actually uncovered a limitation (unsoundness) of Scala's pattern matching, and it can lead to run-time crashes. Here's a simplified example:

```
def foo [B1 >: String](x: B1): Int = {
  val (s1: Int, s2: Int) = (x, x)
  s1
}
```

Although this compiles, it doesn't do anything useful. In fact, it will always crash with a `MatchError`:

```
scala> foo("hello")
scala.MatchError: (hello,hello) (of class scala.Tuple2)
    at .foo(<console>:9)
    at .<init>(<console>:10)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    ...
```

In your answer, you've basically told the compiler to convert a `B1` instance to a `String`, and if the conversion doesn't work, you'll get a runtime crash. It's equivalent to an unsafe cast,

```
(value: B1).asInstanceOf[String]
```

Comment: Apparently a few seconds later, but a far more complete answer than mine. +1

Comment: I think the critical part of the answer here is "But you're trying to define ParamMap.+ to always return ParamMap[String, String], which is incompatible with Map.+."  I liked Schief's answer, too, but if he likes yours better you can have the checkmark.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You're correct that your constructor expects a value of type `List[String, String]`, but the issue isn't that B1 could be a subclass of String, it's that it could be a **superclass** -- this is what the `B1 :> String` notation indicates.

At first glance, you might wonder why the parent `Map` class would have the method typed this way. In fact, the return type of the + method you're attempting to override there is `Map[String, B1]`. In the context of a general map, though, this makes sense. Suppose you had the following code:

```
class Parent
class Child extends Parent

val childMap = Map[String, Child]("Key" -> new Child)

val result = childMap + ("ParentKey" -> new Parent)
```

The type of `result` would then have to be `Map[String, Parent]`. In light of this, the type restrictions on the + method in `Map` makes sense, but your fixed-type map isn't capable of fulfilling what the method is designed to be able to do. Its signature allows you to pass in a value of e.g. type `(String, AnyRef)`, but using the method definition you gave in your followup answer, you'll get a `MatchError` when it tries to perform the assignment to `key` and `value`.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

I ran the same problem with a colleague, when trying to build a `Bag[T]` which is a `Map[T,Int]`. We found two different solutions:

1. Implement `Traversable` rather than `Map` with appropriate `Builder` and `CanBuildFrom`, and add the useful map methods (get,+,-). If you need to pass the collection to a function taking maps as arguments, you can use implicit conversions. Here is our full Bag implementation: https://gist.github.com/1136259
2. Stay simple:

   ```
   object collection {
     type ParamMap = Map[String,String]
     object ParamMap {
       def apply( pairs: List[(String,String)] = Nil ) = Map( pairs:_* )
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hmm it's probably a good point that this isn't really a "Map" in the usual way a Map is in Scala.  Perhaps subclassing map is not a good idea in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does seem to accept this one:

```
  override def + [B1 >: String](kv: (String, B1)) = {
    val (key:String, value:String) = kv
    new ParamMap((key,value) :: pairs)
  }
```

But I don't know why that is better than the original.  I suppose this is an acceptable solution if nobody has a better one.

Comment: This is equivalent to an unsafe cast. My answer has more details.

Comment: Ah I wouldn't have expected this to act like a cast.  That definitely clarifies things, thanks!