# "Too many arguments" error in Scala superclass constructor but not in REPL

Tags: scala, constructor, compiler-errors

I am writing a class which extends Scala's immutable map with some custom constructor logic. As a simple example, say I want a map of integers to strings that is initialized as `1 -> "one", 2 -> "two"`. In the REPL I can write the following.

```
scala> import collection.immutable.HashMap
import collection.immutable.HashMap

scala> HashMap[Int, String](1->"one", 2->"two")
res0: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,String] = Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two)
```

In my program I'd like to use the same constructor call, but I get a "too many arguments for constructor" error when I try to put it in the class definition line.

```
scala> class MyMap extends HashMap[Int, String](1->"1", 2->"2")
<console>:8: error: too many arguments for constructor HashMap: ()scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,String]
   class MyMap extends HashMap[Int, String](1->"1", 2->"2")
               ^
```

Given that the way to call superclass constructors is in the class definition, I figured that any expression that creates a `HashMap` in the REPL should also work in the definition, but there's some subtlety I'm missing here.

(I think extending the concrete class `HashMap` instead of a trait is the right thing to do here because I want to use the default map implementation. Extending `HashMap` is what I'd do in Java, but I'm not 100% certain that extending concrete collection classes is the most Scalaesque way to operate.)

Because I want `MyMap` to be immutable, I need to specify the initial values at constructor time. I can trying doing the initialization inside the `apply` function of the companion object like so:

```
class MyMap extends HashMap[Int, String]

object MyMap {
  def apply() = new MyMap ++ List(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")
}
```

But `MyMap()` returns an immutable map instead of a `MyMap`.

What is the correct way to initialize `MyMap`?

---

This link [about implementing Map with concrete types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004577/scala-implementing-map-with-concrete-types) is relevant.

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get an error here because when you write `Map()` you don't call the constructor of `Map`. Instead you call the apply method of it's companion object (or more precise the apply method of one of its superclasses. See om-nom-noms comment):

```
scala> Map(1 -> "one")
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> one)

scala> Map.apply(1 -> "one")
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> one)
```

If you want to have an own `Map` implementation you need to create your own implementation. The easiest thing I came up with is:

```
object MyMap {
  def apply(ts: (Int, String)*): MyMap[Int, String] = new MyMap(ts.toMap)
  def apply(): MyMap[Int, String] = apply(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")
}

class MyMap[A, B] private(t: Map[Int, B]) extends Map[Int, B]  {
  private val internalMap = t
  def +[B1 >: B](kv: (Int, B1)) = new MyMap(internalMap + kv)
  def -(key: Int) = new MyMap(internalMap - key)
  def get(key: Int) = internalMap.get(key)
  def iterator = internalMap.iterator
}

scala> MyMap()
res1: MyMap[Int,String] = Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two)
```

Comment: Right. That makes sense. I'm still not sure how to get the constructor call I want though. Thinking about it some more, an equivalent question might be "How do I call a copy constructor for `HashMap`?"

Comment: Is it true, that apply method comes to the Map from [GenMapFactory](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenMapFactory.scala#L48) and not directly from [companion object](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L72)?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: eclipse' hyperlinking feature says yes ;) I will edit my post.

Comment: @W.P.McNeill: Why do you want to have an own class that provides initial elements? Is it not possible to add them after you have created the class?

Comment: Modified original question to answer preceding comment from @sschaef

Comment: @W.P.McNeill: I edited my answer. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, @sschaef. That's the answer I was looking for. I was confused because doing a `Map` implementation seems like boilerplate to me, and I thought there would be a way around it. It seems odd that when adding functionality to Scala collection classes you don't have a choice between "wrap" and "extend" but are instead forced to "wrap".

Comment: @W.P.McNeill: It is possible to do both, "wrap" and "extend" the collection classes. But the former is far easier to implement and often enough. The latter would require to implement an own `CanBuildFrom` and probably some `XXXLike` classes, which should only be done if it is really necessary.

Comment: This confirms my suspicion that extending concrete collection classes is in fact _not_ the most Scalaesque way to operate.  Thanks, again.