# Scala extend Map (or HashMap) and allow a constructor list of mappings

Tags: scala

I have a special Map that will eventually do some consistency checking of values, which are restricted to have special meaning. For now I just want to create a Schema that acts exactly like a Map[String, Any], in particular I'd like to instantiate is with a list of mappings, and not force the types for the Map to be specified, so they are always [String, Any]. So instead of

```
val myMap:Map[String,Any] = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> "2", ...)
```

I'd like to be able to have:

```
val mySchema:Schema = Schema("one" -> 1, "two" -> "2", ...)
```

Map is a trait so I think I need to extend a class like HashMap

```
class Schema extends HashMap[String, Any]
```

when I instantiate it with a list of initial mappings I get

```
val mySchema = new Schema("one" -> 1, "two" -> "2", ...)

Error:(110, 19) too many arguments for constructor Schema: ()drivers.Schema
  val mySchema = new Schema("one" -> 1, "two" -> "2")
              ^
```

There is some magic inside HashMap that is far beyond me to read (it `extends` 1 class `with` 5 traits). But it looks like the constructor's "contents" (a list of mappings?) are passed to something's `initWithContents(contents)` pseudo constructor. Do I need something like that there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Schema(elems: Tuple2[String, Any]*) extends HashMap[String, Any] {
    this ++= elems
}

val mySchema = new Schema("one" -> 1, "two" -> "2")
```

Explanation:

- `->` is syntactic sugar for a tuple, so the constructor type is a variable number of tuples
- The "normal" way of constructing a Map/HashMap calls the [apply method in the companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$) which is implemented in [GenMapFactory.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenMapFactory.scala).

Unfortunately, this does not work for an immutable HashMap. As far as I can tell, the only way to "extend" an immutable HashMap is by creating a class that holds an internal reference to one, as described e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13166304/1805388) to a similar question on SO.

Comment: Yes, I understood about tuples but since they are somewhat hidden didn't know how to deal with them directly--thanks. The `this ++= elems` line gets and error because I was using an immutable HashMap. Works fine if I change to mutable. Let me think whether I need immutable, there's a `copy` way to do it for immutable I think?

Comment: I added a paragraph to address the immutable HashMap case.

Answer (score 2):

You'll notice that the syntax you're using to create the `Schema` instance is slightly different than your target syntax as well as the standard `Map` syntax:

```
Schema("one" -> 1, "two" -> "2", ...)
new Schema("one" -> 1, "two" -> "2", ...)
Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> "2", ...)
```

In particular, there is a `new` in the second case. When you create a `Map` without new, you are invoking a function called `apply` on a companion module of the same name. In this case, the function which accepts a variable length sequence of arguments is defined the `Map` object's inherited `GenMapFactory` type and it has this signature:

```
def apply[A, B](elems: (A, B)*): CC[A, B] = (newBuilder[A, B] ++= elems).result
```

The magic derives the from Scala compiler resolving this method, because methods in the companion module are part of its implicit scope. You will need to do something similar in by adding a `Schema` object:

```
object Schema {
  def apply(entries: (String, Any)*) = new Schema() ++ entries
}
```

If you define the `object`, this will work:

```
Schema("one" -> 1, "two" -> "2") // scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any](one -> 1, two -> 2)
```

One downside of this approach is that you lose type specificity after construction, but if you're just performing consistency checking on creation this may be enough. If you want the `Schema` type to be returned on invocation of the `apply` function or returned by other methods calls implemented in super types and enclosing scope, you will probably need to integrate with the Scala 2.8 collections API as documented [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html).

Comment: I think this was taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166140/too-many-arguments-error-in-scala-superclass-constructor-but-not-in-repl/13166304#13166304 and _does_ work on an immutable Map. It seems the downside is that you have to redefine every method you need?

Comment: You're right. I reread your question, and modified the answer to take a lighter approach.